# Get IServiceCollection in Service?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Is there a way to get the IServiceCollection we use at Startup in a Service?
I want to get a list of all current services.
Taking a dependency on it does not work, as the servicecollection is not registered in the DI

```
public class Test
{
    public Test(IServiceCollection collection)
    {
        this.services=collection; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't, because `IServiceCollection` is not registered on the DI. You can, however, inject the `IServiceProvider` itself, from which you can obtain any service.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you add the Dependency Injection using statement you should get a list of all the services. Is that what you're not seeing ?